# dotnet core api returns empty array of braces

Tags: c#, mongodb, controller, .net-core, swagger

I am trying swagger with dotnet core and MongoDB,this is my code ,

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/v1/flight/airports")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetAirports")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(List<Airport>), description: "successful operation")]
    public virtual ActionResult<List<Airport>> GetAirports()
    {
        var air = _airportsService.Get();
        return _airportsService.Get();
    }
```

getting all values while debugging ,

[image]

but on returning getting an empty array of braces in postman , what am I missing here ?

[image]

Comment: What is the return type of the `Get` method?

Comment: why your endpoint method virtual ? try remove the `virtual` keyword and  show the get method code so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So later I figured out my Model was only emitting Bson , added Json attrib also , it started working. Bson for Mongo binding , Json for api out

Before fix,

```
    [BsonElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
```

After fix,

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "code")]
    [BsonElement("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
```